# Converting ruby log parser to PHP

Tags: php, ruby, parsing, logging

I've been looking at creating SRCDS (steam games server) logs parser, which would send data to database.
While doing research on other existing parsers I've stumbled upon https://github.com/tomav/steam_hlds_log_parser, this exactly https://github.com/tomav/steam_hlds_log_parser/blob/master/lib/steam_hlds_log_parser/handler.rb

```
elsif @options[:display_disconnect] && data.gsub(/: "(.+)<\d+><.+><(.+)>" disconnected/).count > 0
    player, player_team = data.match(/: "(.+)<\d+><.+><(.+)>" disconnected/i).captures
    content = { :type => 'disconnect', :params => { :player => player, :player_team => get_short_team_name(player_team) } }
```

While the data.gsub() is pretty selfexplainatory and I guess is almost the same as preg_match, the variables (player, player_team) part is mystery. How does it work and is something similar possible in php without doing a ton of preg_matches to match different parts of the string?
Example log string for the code above is

```
# L 05/10/2000 - 12:34:56: "Player<73><STEAM_ID_LAN><TERRORIST>" disconnected
```

Comment: You'd just create an associative array in PHP and use intermediate variables like `$player`. Where's the issue here?

Comment: Well no particular issue. I know nothing about ruby and I was wondering how this parser works.
Mostly the variable part:
  player, player_team = data.match(/: "(.+)<\d+><.+><(.+)>" disconnected/i).captures
Since that's the only place those variables are set, how does it get exact player and teamname from the string without regex to get exactly them?
If it is somehow in that regex I'm not good in regexes too :P but I think the regex just matches the string that looks like disconnected message

Comment: Well my question was dumb and I should've checked ruby man before asking. http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html#method-i-captures answered my question.

Comment: I see you solved your own problem (good job!) but I posted my answer anyway since I think it'll help clear up your regular expression confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take it line by line:

```ruby
elsif @options[:display_disconnect] && data.gsub(/: "(.+)<\d+><.+><(.+)>" disconnected/).count > 0
```

First this checks if `@options[:display_disconnect]` is truthy (i.e. not `false` or `nil`) and then it checks if the `data` string matches the regular expression between the slashes (`/.../`). This is a really bad way to check for a regular expression match in Ruby (we have `String#match` or `=~` for that), but nevertheless it works. If it's match, we execute the next line:

```ruby
player, player_team = data.match(/: "(.+)<\d+><.+><(.+)>" disconnected/i).captures
```

On the right-hand side of `=` we call [`String#match`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-match) with the same regular expression as before (but with the `i` flag this time—go figure). If it matches (which we already established on the last line), `match` returns a [MatchData](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/MatchData.html) object. This object holds information about about the match, e.g. what position it starts at and, in the [`MatchData#captures`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/MatchData.html#method-i-captures) property, what parts of the string were captured.

In case you're new to regular expressions, parentheses in regular expressions indicate "capture groups." In our regular expression we have two: One captures the player name ("Player" in your example) and the other captures the team name ("TERRORIST"). `captures` returns these two strings as the array `[ "Player", "TERRORIST" ]`.

On the left-hand side of the `=` we have `player, player_team`. The comma indicates "destructuring assignment"—it tells Ruby that, if the value on the right-hand side of `=` behaves like an array, then assign the first element to `player` and the second element to `player_team`, just like [`list()`](http://php.net/list) in PHP. In other words:

```ruby
player, player_team = [ "Player", "TERRORIST" ]

# ...is equivalent to:

captures = [ "Player", "TERRORIST" ]
player = captures[0]      # => "Player"
player_team = captures[1] # => "TERRORIST"
```

Finally:

```ruby
content = { :type => 'disconnect',
            :params => { :player => player,
                         :player_team => get_short_team_name(player_team) }
          }
```

This creates a Hash—which is just like an associative array in PHP—with the `player` and `player_team` values. Its rough equivalent in PHP would be:

```php
$content = array( "type" => 'disconnect',
                  "params" => array( "player" => $player,
                                     "player_team" => get_short_team_name($player_team) )
                );
```

I hope that's helpful!

P.S. Personally I would've written the Ruby code like this:

```ruby
DISCONNECT_EXPR = /: "(.+)<\d+><.+><(.+)>" disconnected/i

# ...

elsif @options[:display_disconnect] && data =~ DISCONNECT_EXPR
    content = { :type => 'disconnect',
                :params => { :player => $1,
                             :player_team => get_short_team_name($2) }
              }
```

There's no reason to use the same regular expression twice, and *really* no reason to use `String#gsub` when we're not actually making any substitutions.